# Finding union of two columns based on the uniqueness of an unrelated column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to determine how each student will perform on a head to head basis with respect to the classes they have been in and projects they have completed.

scores.csv: https://pastebin.com/FxUCb4xT

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Documents/scores.csv")

student_ids = df.student_id.unique()

for id in student_ids:
    to_analyse = pd.merge(df,df[df['student_id'] == id][['class_id','project_id']])
```

I will end up doing my own thing to `to_analyse` but getting there in the first place is awfully slow using `pd.merge` especially if there's 10's of thousands of unique student ids.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I have tried using pivot table but maybe  I'm barking up the wrong tree using that approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think a bit faster is use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
def f(x):
    print (pd.merge(df, x[['class_id','project_id']]))

df = df.groupby('student_id').apply(f)
```

Solution without `merge` with concatenating columns, [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['both'] = df['class_id'].astype(str)  + '_' + df['project_id'].astype(str)

def f(x):
    print (df[df['both'].isin(x['both'])])

df = df.groupby('student_id').apply(f).drop('both', axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jezrael but how would I be able to use each group? Is there a way of storing group in a dictionary instead of printing it out maybe? I tried to count the number of posts in each group using a similar approach: `df.groupby('student_id').transform(lambda x: pd.merge(df, x[['class_id','project_id']])['posts'].sum())` but it didn't work.

Comment: I think you are really close - need `apply` - `df1 = df.groupby('student_id').apply(lambda x: pd.merge(df, x[['class_id','project_id']])['posts'].sum())
`

Comment: And for dict `df1 = df.groupby('student_id').apply(lambda x: pd.merge(df, x[['class_id','project_id']]).to_dict()).to_dict()` (maybe last `to_dict` can be removed, it depends what you want)